# Unable to update from android studio 3.1.4 to 3.4.1

Tags: android-studio, android-studio-3.0

I am trying to update android studio from 3.1.4 to 3.4.1 it showing below error while patch:

```
ERROR Patch.apply - apply failed
java.io.IOException: Impossibile trovare il file specificato
at java.io.FileInputStream.readBytes(Native Method)
at java.io.FileInputStream.read(FileInputStream.java:233)
at com.intellij.updater.Utils.copyStream(Utils.java:237)
at ie.wombat.jbdiff.JBPatch.realAllFileContent(JBPatch.java:141)
at ie.wombat.jbdiff.JBPatch.bspatch(JBPatch.java:67)
at 
com.intellij.updater.DiffAlgorithm$JBDiffAlgorithm.applyDiff
(DiffAlgorithm.java:118)
at 
com.intellij.updater.BaseUpdateAction.applyDiff(BaseUpdateAction.java:145)
at com.intellij.updater.UpdateAction.doApply(UpdateAction.java:55)
at com.intellij.updater.PatchAction.apply(PatchAction.java:199)
at com.intellij.updater.Patch.lambda$apply$3(Patch.java:399)
at com.intellij.updater.Patch.forEach(Patch.java:471)
at com.intellij.updater.Patch.apply(Patch.java:390)
at com.intellij.updater.PatchFileCreator.apply(PatchFileCreator.java:64)
at com.intellij.updater.Runner.install(Runner.java:357)
at com.intellij.updater.Runner.main(Runner.java:131)
```

any clue?

Comment: Have you tried invalidate cache and restart?

Comment: i  invalidate cache and restart. In the restart it crash but at the 2 opening it give no problem and it success the update

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as pointed by @Gabriele Mariotti invalidate cache and restart seems, in the second try, to resolve the problem